# image hyperlink not working in WordPress text widget header

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I located social icons in my text widget located in the header.  It works in IE but not in Chrome or Firefox??  I am wondering if it has to do with my Artisteer 4 theme I am using, but I have looked at all the CSS and code and don't see what is interfering.  My site is http://www.visualtechnologyconsulting.com

and the code in the text widget is:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/visualtechnologyconsulting/">
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-372" alt="Visual Technology Consulting 
Facebook" src="http://www.visualtechnologyconsulting.com/wp-
content/uploads/2013/01/facebook-logo-webtreats.png" width="75" height="75" />
</a>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/visual-technology-consulting/">
<img src="http://www.visualtechnologyconsulting.com/
wp-content/uploads/2013/01/linkedin-logo-webtreats.png" 
alt="Visual Technology Consulting Linkedin" width="75" height="75" 
class="alignnone size-full wp-image-373" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see them in Chrome. Everything looks fine. 
But maybe you post the CSS Part?

Answer (score 0):

Nate, its working for me in Chrome and firefox. [See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRLph.jpg) Have you refreshed your browsers cache?

Comment: it displays, but the hyperlinks are not functioning?  unless its an issue with my local machine?  did the hyperlinks work for you?

Comment: I got it finally, it was a CSS issue

Comment: If you declare a position and set a z-index value, the widget will display above your header and then the links will work. Try this: .textwidget {position: relative; z-index: 100;}

Answer (score 0):

I found it!! it was a CSS issue I was covering the icons with the header div, needed to reduce it to 40%!!!

Thanks everyone!